# dymo labelmanager 280 with lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

Can I use my dymo labelmanager 280 with lubuntu ?
I need to print some labels and I don't know what I need to buy.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You MIGHT find [this page](http://www.opensourcepartners.nl/~costar/dylol/) helpful.  I currently use a Brother USB interface laminated tape printer with a program entirely written by one man who has such a label printer.  There is no actual stand-alone driver for his program.  His program prepares a file which it sends to the printer when you are ready.  You might find a similar program if you look hard enough.